# Issues with Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python

I have just started learning coding. Python is my first language. I was working with multiple inheritance and had written below program for the same:

```
class animal:
    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def show(self):
        print(f"Name : {self.name}")
        print(f"Species : {self.species}")


class dog(animal):
    def __init__(self, name, breed):
        animal.__init__(self, name, species="Dog")
        self.breed = breed

    def show(self):
        animal.show(self)
        print(f"Breed : {self.breed}")

class cat(animal):
    def __init__(self, name, breed):
        animal.__init__(self, name, species="Cat")
        self.breed = breed

    def show(self):
        animal.show(self)
        print(f"Breed : {self.breed}")

class anicolor(dog, cat):
    def __init__(self, name, breed, color):
        dog.__init__(self, name, breed)
        cat.__init__(self, name, breed)
        self.color = color

    def show(self):
        print(dog.show(self), cat.show(self))
        print(f"Color : {self.color}")


d = anicolor("Tommy", "German Shepherd", "Black")
c = anicolor("Kitty", "Persian", "White")

d.show()
c.show()
```

The output I expected was:

```
Name : Tommy
Species : Dog
Breed : German Shepherd
Color : Black
Name : Kitty
Species : Cat
Breed : Persian
Color : White
```

The main issue in the output as shown below is tommy species shown as Cat instead of dog as since cat class constructor is written after dog class constructor. So how to overcome that?

```
Name : Tommy
Species : Cat
Breed : German Shepherd
Name : Tommy
Species : Cat
Breed : German Shepherd
None None
Color : Black
Name : Kitty
Species : Cat
Breed : Persian
Name : Kitty
Species : Cat
Breed : Persian
None None
Color : White
```

Comment: Since Tommy and Kitty are both `anicolor`, which inherits from both `cat` and `dog`, how do you expect the code to know that you want one of them to be a dog and the other to be a cat?

Comment: it would make more sense for `color` to be a property of `animal`, instead by introducing `anicolor` class you create a weird hybrid animal that is both dog and cat at the same time

Comment: The main issue in the output is tommy species shown as Cat instead of dog as since cat class constructor is written after dog class constructor. How to overcome that?

Comment: Building on what @khelwood said, I think you class hierarchy is backwards: `dog` and `cat` should inherit from both `animal` and `anicolor`.

Comment: @Anentropic i am just practicing and getting use on how to apply multiple inheritance.

Comment: *"[..] since cat class constructor is written after dog class constructor. So how to overcome that?"* - don't have a class that inherits from both `cat` and `dog`.

Comment: if you want to distinguish cats and dogs you need to instantiate the object as either a cat or a dog, not "both"... this implies that the color property should live at a lower level of the class hierarchy than cat/dog instead of above it

Comment: also generally you should use `super` instead of directly calling parent class methods, see https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: @Friedrich Is is possible to have a class that inherits both cat & dog class? as i want to write multiple inheritance program. if yes than kindly let me know

Comment: It's possible. You did it and it does not work as expected. OOD should mirror real-world objects. So we got to ask ourselves: is there an animal that *is* both a cat and a dog? You just picked a poor example for your exploration into multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Anentropic thanks. i solved that by using super..

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative class hierarchy that works and still makes use of multiple inheritance:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def show(self):
        print(f"Name : {self.name}")
        print(f"Species : {self.species}")


class Colored:
    def __init__(self, color, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = color

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print(f"Color : {self.color}")


class WithBreed:
    def __init__(self, breed, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.breed = breed

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        print(f"Breed : {self.breed}")


class Dog(WithBreed, Colored, Animal):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(species="Dog", **kwargs)


class Cat(WithBreed, Colored, Animal):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(species="Dog", **kwargs)


d = Dog(name="Tommy", breed="German Shepherd", color="Black")
c = Cat(name="Kitty", breed="Persian", color="White")

d.show()
c.show()
```

In this example `Animal` is our base class and `Colored` and `WithBreed` are "mixins" that can be applied to any class

We make our `Cat` and `Dog` types as `Animal`s that have the `Colored` and `WithBreed` behaviours.

Each class only sees the arguments it cares about for its specific behaviour while passing the rest around as `kwargs` allowing you to change the definition of base class, or add or remove mixins, without updating the code in every other class.

(If we think about this class hierarchy further we might consider that `WithBreed` only makes sense for animals, so probably that should not be a separate class and just part of `Animal`, but the `Colored` mixin could potentially be used for other types of things like `Vehicle` or `Milkshake`, so it makes sense as a mixin)

Comment: @KrunalSmart if you find this answer useful, consider giving it your vote by pressing the up arrow to its left. If it solves your problem, accept the answer by pressing the V-shaped button. This is how we say "thank you" on SO.